# does DEVC/DEVC++ IDE not support vectors

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vect1(10);
    int value = 5;
    fill(vect1.begin(), vect1.end(), value);
    for (int x : vect1)
        cout << x << " ";
}
```

this does not compile in dev c++ and shows error.. i directly copied this code from gfg--> link is https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/initialize-a-vector-in-cpp-different-ways/.

EDIT : it says range based for loops are not allowed in cpp98 version

im new to cpp any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Visual studio can't compile it either: https://godbolt.org/z/a7av6jrEn

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: i'd not suggest using `bits/stdc++.h`

Comment: But seriously, There are many different variants of Dev C++ and some of them come with 20-year old compilers that just can't handle modern code. [Here's a link to a more modern edition](https://github.com/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/releases) with a compiler that's only a few years old.

Comment: [Explanation of why Abhilekh Gautam's probably right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Answer (score 1):

Probably, Dev C++ has C++98 as default, and range-based for loop is from C++11 and onwards.

You click on Tools:
[image]

Click on Compile Options:
[image]

Click on Settings:
[image]

Click on Code Generation:
[image]
On language standards, choose "ISO C++11"
[image]

But you shouldn't use Dev C++ anymore.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not the compiler.
The `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is a standard header which most of the sites use in their example codes and it includes a lot of other c++ header files but this is not defined in any C++ standard and not recommended at all because all compilers doesn't support it and it effects the portability of the code.

Here is the detailed explanation of this:
[Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)